# power bi embedded link with current log in liferay user

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded

I have a power bi pro license and i developed a report in power bi using liferay data. now i want to publish the report in life ray using publish to web but only want to show data to the user who logged in liferay. like x@x.com or userid x logged in liferay and accessed power bi page, then it should see his filtered data. i tried making RLS but not sure how it will work and when publishing with RLS report it asks for signin.

i tried RLS but when published to web it was asking sign in.

Comment: LMK if you have any other queries.

Answer (score 0):

Publish to Web doesn't support RLS. Refer to [publish-to-web-limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-publish-to-web#considerations-and-limitations).

Refer [Embed a report with RLS](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/developer/embedded/cloud-rls) for embedding report with RLS. We need to pass RLS identities additionally when generating Embed token.

Comment: I am not sure how to work around. very new to liferay and power bi